# Cloning freebsd to new machine

Tags: unix, clone, freebsd, iso

I am having freebsd installed on a physical machine. On this machine I have installed many things which I don't want to install again and again if i use freebsd on a new machine.

So, Is there any way I can clone same freebsd setup to the different machines.Or can I create .iso image of the live running freebsd. Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Fastest way might be to mount some external storage and use dd to create the image of the whole disk ("dd if=/dev/ada0 of=/mnt/external/disk.img bs=1m"), and then write the image to the new disk.  If this is SSD, remember to use "fsck_ufs -E /" on the new disk.